# How can I wake up my Mac from sleep mode remotely?

Tags: remote-control

I use logmein to remotely control my computers.
Can I wake up the Mac when it's in sleep mode so that it's offline to the outside world?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From this [post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020220095929695):

> Most modern computers offer a feature
>   called "Wake on LAN". This is designed
>   to allow a network administrator to
>   turn on a computer remotely, even when
>   it is turned off, by sending a "magic
>   packet". This is used, for instance,
>   to allow backup programs to run at
>   night.
>
> Here is a Python script that does this
>   (if your MAC address is01-23-45-67-89-0a:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import socket 
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
s.sendto('\xff'*6+'\x01\x23\x45\x67\x89\x0a'*16, ('192.168.1.255', 80))
```

Or you can use [Wake550](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~olve0003/wake550.html).

or use this [site](http://www.dslreports.com/wakeup).

Comment: Wake On LAN requires another computer on the subnet to be awake, or the Router to support WoL. If this was the case, LogMeIn would already offer the 'Wake Up This Computer' option.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, I've accomplished this by two means. First, both methods require you to check "Wake for Network Access" in System Preferences -> Energy Saver

[image: System Preferences - Energy Saver]

(1) If you open Finder, expand the "Shared" section if necessary, and connect to the sleeping computer!

This works occasionally, but not every time. The bonus is that (presumably) at this point, I'm doing what I needed to do anyways.

(2) If that failed, I generally open [Wake On LAN](http://www.readpixel.com/wakeonlan/index.html) and manually send a Wake request to the computer.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Wake On LAN : http://www.readpixel.com/wakeonlan/index.html

Comment: Well, I'm glad you know how to search, because I completely forgot to put the actual link in there! Thanks ;).

Answer (score 3):

@Am1rr3zA, I had to add one line to your Python script to make it work, as documented on [this page](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020220095929695):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import socket 
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto('\xff'*6+'\x01\x23\x45\x67\x89\x0a'*16, ('192.168.1.255', 80))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also wake up your Mac over wireless.

First, your Mac must support Wake on Wireless. Second, your router must support Wireless Multimedia Extensions (WME), also known as Wi-Fi Multimedia (WMM).

After your enabled WME on your router, you must enable "Wake for network access" on your Mac. Then check the MAC address of your wireless card of your Mac. Put your Mac into sleep. From a second computer log in to your router and with the WOL (Wake on LAN) option wake up your Mac wirelessly by entering the MAC address.

Remember, not every router supports WME.

Comment: I believe the both Apple Airport Express and TimeCapsule support this feature.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And also other routers have this feature, for example WRT54GL (I'm using this one).